# ASP.NET Provider Model for Data Access

Tags: .net, ado.net, data-access-layer, provider

Just been introduced to the ASP.NET Provider Model as a potential data-access technology.  My own idea is to use LINQ repositories, but want to keep an open mind.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is the web framework for .NET, and has nothing to do with data access.

It does use the provider model for many functions, including membership.  Perhaps you're mixing this up with data access?

If you're interested in using the provider model for switching out your repository after compile time with different implementations, you need to look at Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control frameworks such as MS' Unity.

Comment: There is a provider model in ADO, but it's largely concerned with hiding whether the database is, say, SQL Server or Oracle.